# Select Text within 'embed' for pdf document

Tags: javascript, pdf, web-scraping, select, range

I am attempted to scrape information off a website which apparently uses an 'embed' to display a pdf window.  The code is very simple and I've found a method for sending the information.

If I 'ctrl + a' the pdf window, it will select everything.  At which point, I can now send the information as needed through a message.

My problem is, that I need a method to select and set the range on the information automatically.  Preferably not manually.

The html is pretty easy:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body class="pdf">
<embed name="0111111" style="position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0;" width="100%" height="100%" src="about:blank" type="application/pdf" internalid="0111111">
</body>
</html>
```

That really is all of it.  The stuff is apparently inside the embed.  As I said, I can 'ctrl + a' and highlight everything and get the info sent as needed, but I can't seem to figure out how to automatically select the text inside the embed.

My current code is:

```
// Send Selected Info Inside PDF
document.querySelector('embed').postMessage({type: 'getSelectedText'}, '*');

// Listen for info inside PDF
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  console.log(event.data.selectedText);
}, false);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

document.querySelector('embed').postMessage({type: 'selectAll'});

This works perfectly...  You put it into the content script.

```
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  console.log(event.data.selectedText);
}, false);

const script = document.createElement('script');

script.textContent = `(${() => {
        document.querySelector('embed').postMessage({type: 'selectAll'});
        document.querySelector('embed').postMessage({type: 'getSelectedText'}, '*');
      }})()`;
document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
script.remove();
```

Comment: Reference #1: 
 https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:chrome/browser/resources/pdf/pdf_scripting_api.js
Reference #2:  http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/android/android-4.0/external/chromium/chrome/common/extensions/docs/content_scripts.html
Reference #3:  https://www.mejorcodigo.com/p/20633.html

Comment: Reference #1 (file moved): https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/browser/resources/pdf/pdf_scripting_api.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the pdf 's content within the `embed` tag through javascript in the browser.

I suggest that if you are in the `Node.js` environment, after getting the url of pdf file, you may download it and search for a pdf parser on `npm` to extract the text content of this file.

Comment: I just said I was able to successfully access it through the provided script.  All I need now is a way to highlight everything on the screen successfully.  Is there not a way to select all content on the screen?  Also, the url appears to be blank, I found evidence that it uses a 'get' somewhere, but that information is blocked while in strict mode.

Comment: I figured it out.  Thanks though.