# Is it possible to interact with PDF-VIEWER (Selenium or other tools)?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This issue has been driving me crazy lately, I've been looking all over the internet for days and just found unaswered questions.

Is it possible in any way to interact with the pdf-viewer extension inside a chrome browser? I'm simply looking for a way to press the "print" button marked in red as shown in the first picture, and then the blue button that says "skriv ut" as shown in the second picture. Can this be done in any way with either selenium/javascript or any other tools or am i wasting my time? Thanks in advance!

Here is a test site: https://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf

**First picture:**
[image]

**Second picture:**
[image]

Comment: I'm looking for a way to interact with the elements inside that popup, i dont really want to use sendkeys or those shortcuts because problems can arise very fast doing that. Do you know a way using example Selenium to interact with the elements of that popup? I am currently using autohotkey with selenium, but cant find a way to touch those elements.

Thanks for taking your time!

Comment: You'd have to switch to the embed and then proceed to go through shadow roots which is a massive pain.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Sure, but I cant even connect to the pdf window where the shadow roots are located, have you found a way to do this?

Comment: I think you need to go to developer tools and then look for an embed element.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Yeah, i found it and switched to it, but still couldn't access anything. Please if you have time try it out with the following site and give me your feedback if you find something (https://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf)

Comment: Have you tried `document.querySelector('embed').postMessage({type: 'print'});`? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68041520/3917161